# Get Multiple List From An Ordered List in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

i have this list in C#:

[image]

and i wanna divide it to 4 list like this :

[image]

how can i do this with Linq?

Comment: So something like [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to group by Field1, so use `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
var field1GroupLists = mainList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Field1)
    .Select(group => group.ToList())
    .ToList();
```